# "Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar" when starting the Scala interpreter

Tags: java, scala, ubuntu

When running the Scala interpreter in Ubuntu 14.04, I get the following message printed as the first line:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
```

Followed by the familiar "Welcome to Scala" message.

I'm worried because I haven't seen that when running Scala before - what does it mean, is it dangerous, etc?

Apparently the environment variable `$JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` is set to `-javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar` - I didn't set that, but what did and why? Can I safely unset it?

Additional info:

- recently installed Android Studio
- The word "ayatana" in the JAR's name might point to Ubuntu's project [Ayatana](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ayatana)

Comment: There is a bug filed against Ubuntu for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jayatana/+bug/1441487

Comment: This really has nothing to do with jayatanaag per se; the problem is the JVM insists on printing out the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS if it's set. If the env var is unset, nothing is printed. Set it to `export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-DFOOBAR="HelloWorld"`, and you'll get that message instead.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can disable jayatana just for the current shell session by unsetting `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` like so:

```
unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
```

That way it will still be enabled for applications needing it.

Comment: where actully write this ??in my terminal ?

Comment: yes, in your terminal before you start the application or in a startup script

Comment: sir, when this error was generated still my application uploaded to playstore. its not affect to play store. so can you please tell me what is the meaning of this error ,sorry for bad english :(

Answer (score 29):

This occurs if you have installed jayatana which allows the hidden global menu in eclipse to work with Unity:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danjaredg/jayatana
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jayatana
```

that puts JARs in the `/usr/share/java/` folder which is echoed by the JVM when starting up.

If you remove that software, you will not see the message:

```
sudo apt-get remove jayatana
```

You may have to delete:

```
/usr/share/upstart/sessions/jayatana.conf
```

and restart your session so that the environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` is not set.

Comment: *"`sudo apt-get install jayatana`"* - did you mean **uninstall**? Is there a way to *suppress* the message, but keep the software?

Comment: I do not want to remove jayatana, Is there any problem in future?

Comment: Suggesting to move a an installation which might have some benefit without saying why of what might result from it is a concern.  I would rather to live with the notice than to loose what might be important functionality.  Do have any idea of what might be a consequence of blatantly removing the software?

Comment: @L.D.James if you remove jayatana, menus of java swing based applications (at least) such as eclipse and intellij will move back inside the window of the application.

Comment: @Caballero Thanks for the input.  The application/java program that I'm running is totally text base.  No gui is installed or involved.  So swing doesn't have anything to do in this case.  It isn't clear to me by your response what effect uninstalling/removing jayatana would have on applications or what benefit is has.  So far I see references to it as giving warning, and suggestions of removing it.  But I'm still looking for whatever benefit it might have and what you might loose if you remove it.  I'll bring what I find back to this answer.  If someone else knows, thanks for input.

Comment: @L.D.James There's no other benefit except of what I said pretty much. "Java Swing Ayatana is a project that brings Ubuntu global menu (AppMenu) and HUD support for Java Swing applications." See this for more info: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/get-unity-global-menu-hud-support-for.html

Comment: @Caballero That clears up my question.  I might have missed the "no other benefit", but the link helped a lot.

Comment: For those who need to enjoy the global menu without this irritating error message, i have found a workaround and shared it here: http://www.javahelps.com/2015/06/global-menu-support-for-java.html#remove-jayatana-message

Answer (score 6):

This is because of Jayatana, which is added to Ubuntu 15.04 in order to enable global menu for Java Swing applications. You can safely remove this message by entering the following command in a terminal. This command will remove the auto-start configuration of Jayatana.

```
sudo rm /usr/share/upstart/sessions/jayatana.conf
```

However, removing this option will disable the global menu support of Java Swing applications like Netbeans, IntelliJ IDEA. I have shared my workaround to suppress the message without losing the global menu in this article: [Global Menu Support for Java Applications](http://www.javahelps.com/2015/06/global-menu-support-for-java.html)

Answer (score 2):

On Windows,
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=

Setting to null will remove it from the environment.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows OS, goto environment variables and delete or set to null the varible JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are dealing with this error working with Groovy scripts, and working with another console (such as Git Bash), change the variable name `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` for `JAVA_OPTS`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to uninstall anything you can create a key store from a terminal:

```
keytool -keystore clientkeystore -genkey -alias anyalias
```

(you should create it at project's forlder)

And then in Android Studio click Build->Generate Signed APK and choose created keystore.